# Synchronize a part of two worksheets in Excel 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to build a workbook in excel where I want to synchronize a part of two sheets with each other. I search around on the internet but didn't find the solution yet. Basically what I want is that the first 8 columns of the first sheet are automatically filled in and updated on the second sheet. So both sheets have more than 8 columns, the first 8 are the same and should be synchronized, the rest is different. More specific criteria are that if a row is added on sheet 1 it should also added on sheet 2. Thereby it should also not be disturbed by sorting. So if you sort another column (9 or higher) it should not disturb the other sheet columns.

There must be a way to do it but just can't find the right way. Has anyone a solution, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well I don't know about the "add extra row". But the first part you should easily do by =Sheet1!A1

Comment: I can do that easily with =Sheet1!A1 but then when i sort sheet 1 differently the rows in the extra columns (9and higher) are not moving along with the referenced cells. So, that doesn't work for me. Thereby I also as you mention can not add extra rows in sheet 1 which are automatically added in sheet 2. Does anybody have additional ideas/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pivot table from the first sheet and place it in the second sheet. That way, anything you update in the first sheet should appear in the second sheet (after refreshing the table).

Comment: I thought about a pivot but that doesn't work for me because in sheet 2 I want to add more columns and the ability to sort on those columns which aren't synchronized with the other sheet.